# Background image won't stick to corner on mobile

Tags: css, background-image

Got a question specifically about the background image on a simple site I'm building.

http://polyamsterdam.nl/

The background image in question is behaving like it should (or at least as I want it to) on my laptop. It sticks to the bottom right corner of the screen.

On mobile (tested it on iPhone so far) the image also sticks to the bottom right corner but if there's more content then fits the screen the background image is pushed to the bottom of the page (instead of just the bottom of the screen).

Haven't been able to find a solution in the archive so I hope someone is able to help.

Thanks, Peter

Comment: A specific page that shows the problem on mobile is:
http://polyamsterdam.nl/20160120_polyamoriecafe.html

Answer (score 0):

I only tested in browserstack but adding this fixed the problem in Chrome for Android:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Edit:
I misunderstood the question. The best way I can think to fix this is to apply the background to an element that has the dimensions of the screen and has `position: fixed` set to it. The way backgrounds work, you will always get the image pushed to the bottom. Don't forget to set the `z-index` correctly (to -1 for instance) to make it stick to the back of the page.

So, in your HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="heartbackground"></div>
    <!-- the rest of your HTML... after this -->
</body>
```

Then in your CSS

```
#heartbackground {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work on iOS

I've added the code for the following page:
http://polyamsterdam.nl/20160120_polyamoriecafe.html

On iOS the background image is still pushed of the screen.

Comment: I misuderstood the question, sorry. This solution won't do

Comment: No problem, someone else may have a solution :)

Comment: I presented a different solution that might help.

Comment: Seeing and trying it now

Comment: Feeling like a real newbie now, trying to understand what you mean ... Below the code I'm currently using for the background image (two sizes of the image for smaller and bigger screens).

[@]media (min-width: 769px) {body {background:url(images/polyamsterdam_screen.jpg) fixed no-repeat bottom left; overflow-x: hidden;}}

[@]media (max-width: 768px) {body {background:url(images/polyamsterdam.jpg) fixed no-repeat bottom left; overflow-x: hidden;}}

The top part of the code is doing just fine, the bottom part is for smaller screens and messes up on at least iOS.

Comment: Thanks, no rush. I'll have to do some shopping, be back in a while.

Comment: Thanks, got it working!

Made some small changes, final code I used is as follows.

CSS
#heartbackground {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

BODY
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="heartbackground"><img src="images/polyamsterdam_screen.jpg"></div>

<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg" id="heartbackground"><img src="images/polyamsterdam.jpg"></div>

Thanks!